# How can I get 'realurl' url of page in backend of Typo3

Tags: php, content-management-system, typo3, backend

I have started to develope a 'post edit content hook' now I need to get 'realurl' of desired page. How can I do this?

I have registered a hook:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tcemain.php']['processDatamapClass'][]
    = 'EXT:' . $_EXTKEY .'/Classes/Hooks/ContentEdit.php:\xxx\xxx\Hooks\ContentEdit';
```

and Class:

```
   class ContentEdit

{
    function processDatamap_postProcessFieldArray($status, $table, $id, &$fieldArray, &$pObj) {
        if($table == 'pages'){
            if ($id !== null){
                // need to get url of page
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no direct way to do this, as RealURL relies on `TSFE` which isn't available on BE, anyway there's workaround extension created by Dmitry Dulepov - author of RealURL - [**Page path**](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/pagepath) which allows you to grab resolved RU path within BE module, scheduler's task, etc.

**NOTE:** This ext just makes a call to the eID script, which generates proper page path, in other words it simulates FE click, therefore it will probably will be able to work not only with RU, but also with CoolURI and other similar extensions.

Comment: Nice, didn't know that one... always built my links by manually instantiating TSFE.